# Java threading queue with thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, input, linked-list, output

I have made a program which uses a single thread to read data from a file into a linked list lets call it LL1. From this i have made a thread pool which allocates each thread with a processing task which reads data from LL1 and outputs its calculations to a new linked-list. 
From this i need to output each threads new linked-list into a SINGLE file. I'm trying to output each linked list in sequential blocks so that threads don't mix the data so i have used a synchronization point as follows:

```
public synchronized void appendContents(List<Vector2> output1) {
    try {
        sFileName = outFilePath + "\\file" +fileCount+ ".cntr";
        File oFile = new File(sFileName);
        if (!oFile.exists()) {
            oFile.createNewFile();
        }
        if (oFile.canWrite()) {
            //BufferedWriter oWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sFileName, true));
             FileWriter wstream = new FileWriter(oFile, true);
             BufferedWriter outWriter = new BufferedWriter(wstream);
             for(int i = 0; i < output1.size(); i++)
             {
                //replace the space marker values with a newline
                if(output1.get(i).y == -200.0){
                outWriter.newLine();
                }else{
                outWriter.write(String.valueOf(output1.get(i).x) + " " + String.valueOf(output1.get(i).y) + " " + String.valueOf(interval));
                outWriter.newLine();    
                }
             }           
             outWriter.close();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException oException) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error appending/File cannot be written: \n" + sFileName);
    }
```

The problem i am facing is that the data isn't coming out in order which is what i need i.e.

```
list1 value                              list1 value
list1 value         _______________\     list2 value
list1 value         ________________\    list1 value 
list2 value         RATHER THAN ____/    list3 value
list2 value         ---------------/     list2 value
list2 value                              list1 value
list3 value                              list2 value
list3 value                              list1 value
list3 value                              list3 value
list3 value                              list3 value
```

If anybody could give me a step in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Show us how you start your threads. Also clarify which result you are getting and which you are expecting.

Comment: maybe this [example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#fe) would help

Comment: What is the resource that you need to synchronize access to?  It seems likely that it is the `List<Vector2>`.  You should probably lock on that, rather than use the implicit lock of the object to which appendContents() belongs.  As written, in a highly concurrent environment, your appendContents() method will possibly become a bottleneck and limit scalability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `synchronized` is to synchronize on a shared resource so that only one `Thread` gets access to a critical section at a single time. I'm going to assume that you are spawning three `Thread` instances that each call `appendContents` on their own object.

A `synchronized` method implicitly synchronizes on `this`, but since all three `Thread`s are synchronized on a different object, ie. a different `this`, there's nothing blocking either of them.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, You run every time new task for every list element?

then you just can write Callable task -> save result in Feature.Put Feature in List vs result(resultFeatureFromList). and at the end make some thing like this :
i use Function from Guava Lib;

```
Iterables.transform(resultList<Feature>,new Function(){
   public resultComputition apply(Feature resultFeatureFromList){
               return resultFeatureFromList.get();
   }
});
```

So in conclusion, you will run all task in right order. and after pulling all simply wait for result.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating from [user2870704's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19318689/2088822), you may structure your application as follows:

- Have a thread read the file contents;
- For each item in the file, submit a `Callable` task to your thread pool;
- Store the returned `Future` in a list, or list of lists - you define the granularity you need;
- Open the output file, **in the same thread**, and traverse the results list to write.

As an example:

```
void readAndOutput(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath) {
    List<List<Future<Result>>> results = readAndSpawnTask(inputFilePath);

    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFilePath));

    for (List<Future<Result>> block : results) {
        for (Future<Result> r : block) {
            out.println(r.get().toString());
        }
    }

    out.flush();
    out.close();
}


List<List<Future<Result>>> readAndSpawnTask(String path) {
    List<List<Future<Result>>> results = new ArrayList<>(numOfBlocks);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBlocks; ++i) {
        results.add(new LinkedList<Future<Result>>());
    }

    for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
        int respectiveBlock;
        Callable<Result> task;
        // Process line and convert it into a task of your own.
        // Determine in which block the result goes into.
        Future<Result> r = threadPool.submit(task);
        results.get(respectiveBlock).add(r);
    }

    in.close();

    return results;
}
```

If you want and / or need concurrency, the idea is to access files in a single thread. Using a list of `Future`, you have guarantees of writing the results in the right order, and your main thread will block until the needed result is ready.

Of course, you still have to account for the possible exceptions thrown in the above code.